# how to get permission from instagram to download media in iOS app

Tags: permissions, authorization, instagram

I have seen many apps that is gave option to download media that is from instagram app.

I m creating app with the same functionality (download photo and video) from instagram posts. I have  successfully implemented that in my app and i have submitted the app to app store, but apple says

**we still found that your app allows users to download media without authorization from the relevant third party sources.**

**Solution from apple - Please provide documentary evidence of your rights to allow media downloading from third-party sources.**

So, my question is that how we can get that permission that allows us to download meadia from instagram.

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for permisstion using their official email, such as:

Dailymotion : notifications@dailymotion.com

Facebook : ip@fb.com

Instagram : ip@instagram.com

Periscope: copyright@periscope.tv

Twitter : copyright@twitter.com

Vimeo : dmca@vimeo.com